# Retrieving image in django, update/replace image in django

Tags: django, image, django-models

Hi I have saved an image using my django project with the help of models 
as

```
    Image =  models.ImageField(upload_to="images/profileimages/")
    name = models.CharFiled(max_length=20) 
    #rest of the fileds.
```

Once I have saved this information I want to change/update it. For this i have used a view as

```
    def Information_change(request):
       instance = get_object_or_404(information,pk=request.user.id)
         if request.method == 'POST':
              iform = informationForm(instance=instance, data=request.POST,          files=request.FILES)
               if iform.is_valid():
                     instance = iform.save()
                     return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
         iform = informationForm(instance=instance)
         return render_to_response('registration/information_change.html',{'iform':iform}, RequestContext(request))
```

In my templates am getting all the information in realated fields like name fields contains my name and all the charfields are showing the information, but the image fileds did not show the image/path or any other thing. Rest of the fields can be changed and i am able to edit my name fileds but unable to replace/change the image using this code. how can I fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
My .html file contains

```
  {% block content %}
{% if iform.errors %}
    <p style="color: red;">
    Please correct the error{{ iform.errors|pluralize }} below.
    </p>
{% endif %}
<form method="post" action=".", enctype="multipart/form-data>
    {{ iform.as_p }}    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: post your form in question as well

Comment: These is comma ',' in your form tag after action, not sure that is required. Also, can you verify if you get file in `request.FILES`.

Comment: @AamirAdnan 
my forms.py contains
    class informationForm(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
  model=information
  fields = ('Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Designation', 'Department', 'Location', 'Image')

Comment: @Rohan yes you are right "," is not required. Also request.FILES is not getting file.

Comment: I dont know what the hell is wrong with this code. :( :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all do what `@Rohan` has suggested you. In your view you have a bug, what if there was a case when your form is not valid? Then your `view` will not return an `HTTP response` because you have not handled that. Just remove the `else` of `if request.Method == 'POST'` and indent back following two lines:

```
iform = informationForm(instance=instance)
return render_to_response('registration/information_change.html',{'iform':iform}, RequestContext(request))
```

This will fix the bug which I mention. May be that will show some form errors which is related  to image field.

Comment: Also specify the url in action attribute as well action="{% url url_name %}" where `url_name` is the name of url for this view.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues in your `form` tag:

- comma ',' after *actions* attribute
- No closing quote for `enctype` attribute value